# check whether email is sent successfully or not with firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I'm building an app with react native with firebase authentication. I want to show alert dialog that tells the user that "password reset email was sent" when the email was successfully sent by firebase.

I've been trying to do this in this way

```
    firebase
    .auth()
    .sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
    .then(Alert.alert('','Your password reset mail has been sent'))
    .catch(error => Alert.alert('Error', error.message));
```

using this alert box is been always executed no matter email is actually sent or not. if there is any error two alert dialogs are being displayed.

all I wanted to do is alert the user only when the email was sent successfully and if any error occurs only error alert box should be displayed.

Help me...

Comment: Are you sure your brackets are not the issue? It looks like you don't have the closing bracket for the `then`

Comment: oh!! sorry that was my mistake while copying. i'll edit it. 
brackets are not the issue!!

Comment: Per the documents: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email - the email should be sent if it hits the “.then”. What happens for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what `Alert.alert` does in your code. But if `Alert.alert` does not return a function, then that could be the issue in the code here.

`Promise.then` and `Promise.catch` expect functions as the first argument.

You can try this as a fix:

```
firebase
    .auth()
    .sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
    .then(() => Alert.alert('','Your password reset mail has been sent'))
    .catch(error => Alert.alert('Error', error.message));
```

Instead of directly calling `Alert.alert` in the first argument of `then`, wrap it in an anonymous function.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
        .then(() => Alert.alert('', 'Your password resset mail has been sent'))
        .catch(error => Alert.alert('Error', error.message));
```